# How to custom fields add while fetch V1/invoices API in magento2?

Tags: magento2.2.2

I have tried to add custom fields but I am not able to add it.
I have already extended "magento-sales" default module also routes set but not able to add some fields like "billing_address".

Thanks,

Advance